# Opening different files within if statements in fortran

Tags: if-statement, fortran

I'm a beginner on FORTRAN so maybe what I'm asking is trivial, but I haven't found a solution: I have 2 different files to be read, do some calculation, and then write the result in a different file that depends on the input file. I tried fisrt a simple approach:

```
       real*4 counts,par,deg,fl
       integer*2 i
       character*13 input_file

       WRITE(*,*) "Name of file"
       READ(*,*) input_file
       OPEN(3,FILE=input_file)
       IF (input_file .EQ. 'filename1.dat') THEN
       OPEN(4,FILE='filename1_done.dat',STATUS='NEW')
       par=3.5
       ELSE
       OPEN(4,FILE='filename2_done.dat',STATUS='NEW')
       par=2.1
       END IF
       i = 0
       do
       i = i+1
       READ(3,*,END=99) counts,deg
       fl = 10**(counts)*par
       WRITE(4,*) counts,deg,fl
       END DO
   99  CONTINUE
       CLOSE (3)
       END
```

My problem is that when IF returns false, it performs the calculation with the right value for par but it still calls the output file 'filename1_done.dat'. Even including the loop inside the IF statement and using different units for the output file didn't work. I feel that I'm missing something completely obvious, but can't figure out what. 
PS: I never learned the syntax for FORTRAN 90, but I'm trying to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the error, i.e. typing `filename2.dat` when asked produced `filename2_done.dat`, as expected. It occurred to me that you are seeing `filename1_done.dat` as a result of an earlier run. In this case the reason you don't see `filename2_done.dat` could be that you never give the command `close(4)`.

Comment: That was the problem indeed, thanks a lot. I knew it was something simple

Comment: Great stuff, glad I could help.